# How to re-use parameters file between Capifony releases?

Tags: symfony, capifony

On the [docs page](http://capifony.org/), it's mentioned that you can just create your app's `parameters.yml` file in the `shared/app/config/` folder on remote server. Capifony should then symlink this file in as the real `parameters.yml` file.

However when I run a deployment, the following is output on my deployment machine (verbose):

```
--> Updating Composer dependencies
  * executing "sh -c 'cd /var/www/app-stage/releases/20140219212733 && SYMFONY_ENV=prod php composer.phar update --no-dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress'"
    servers: ["stage-server"]
    [stage-server] executing command
 ** [out :: stage-server] Loading composer repositories with package information
 ** [out :: stage-server] Updating dependencies
 ** [out :: stage-server] Nothing to install or update
 ** [out :: stage-server] Writing lock file
 ** [out :: stage-server] Generating optimized autoload files
 ** [out :: stage-server] Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
 ** [out :: stage-server] Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
 ** [out :: stage-server] Installing assets using the hard copy option
 ** [out :: stage-server] Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
 ** [out :: stage-server] Installing assets for Pucs\KioskBundle into web/bundles/pucskiosk
 ** [out :: stage-server] Installing assets for FOS\JsRoutingBundle into web/bundles/fosjsrouting
```

It seems that when composer update is run, it's producing a new parameters.yml file. But Capifony never deletes it and symlinks in a new one.

Why isn't Capifony symlinking in the parameters.yml file? Do I need additional steps other than just creating the file in the shared dir? Maybe explicitly adding the symlink in my `deploy.rb` file?

#### Edit: here is my deploy.rb (missing a few settings from `staging.rb`)

```
set :stages,        %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
set :stage_dir,     "app/config/deploy"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "kiosk"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "***"
set :scm,         :git
set :deploy_via,  :remote_cache

set :model_manager, "doctrine"

set :use_sudo,      false
set :use_composer,   true
set :update_vendors, true
set :copy_vendors,   true

set  :keep_releases,  3

after "deploy" do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && php app/console cache:clear --env=prod"
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod"
end

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Comment: added above in an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have read the documentation ;) http://capifony.org/#symfony2_deployment

You're missing the `:shared_files` parameters.

```
set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
```